# Error when trying to delete all chart objects in a PowerPoint Slide from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I have an Excel file that servs as a DB.
After sorting and modifying the data in the Excel file, I am copying the updated data to a PowerPoint Slide.
Before copying all chart objects from the updated worksheet, I want to delete the old charts from the PowerPoint Slide.

I have used the piece of code below, however, I am getting an error message when trying to delete the last Chart in the Slide.
The error message is "*Shapes.Item: Integer out of range. 25 is not Index's valid range of 1 to 24*".

```
Dim SlideNum, i                     As Integer

SlideNum = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 2)

For i = 1 To PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes.Count
    ' if current slide object is a chart, delete it
    If PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes.Item(i).HasChart Then
        PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes.Item(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Count backwards with `i`, not forwards.  Going forwards, as you delete shapes at some point `i` will be greater than the number of shapes on the slide (`Shapes.Count` does not get re-evaluated as you loop through the shapes).

Comment: Good practice to declare variables is ~DIM SlideNum As Integer, i As Integer~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are looping through a collection of objects in VBA with the intention of deleting one or more of them you need to count backwards with Step -1 so your loop should start like this:

```
For i = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1
```